# Toyota idling badly, won't go over 3000 revs when driving and stalls

Tags: toyota, stall

Hey I own a 1993 Toyota trueno,
recently the car would stall out of nowhere, both in cold and hot engine temp. when starting up the revs will dip from 1000 to 500 and if I try to accelerate from a stationary, it will sometimes stall with all manner of check engine lights coming on telling me nothing. I've tried replacing the fuel pump but still has problems,
would be awesome if i could sort this problem out myself rather than spending money I don't have at the mechanic, 
thanks!

Comment: When was this last serviced?

Comment: Have you had the check engine light scanned?

Comment: last serviced around 4-5 months ago.

Comment: also check engine light only comes on when car stalls, as well as all the other warning lights, nothing comes up when driving. also noticed when I'm in park I can get it upto 7000rpm but when I'm try foot flat in drive the rpms only slowly rise upto around 3000

Answer (score -1):

Check maf sensor. My maxima pretty mucjh was doing the same.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you elaborate as to why it could be the MAF? Also include how one would go about checking the MAF. We try not to promote Remove & Replace mechanics here on this site, as it usually just costs more money and fixes absolutely nothing. A good answer will include diagnostic methods used to fix an issue as well as the reasons why it might be the cause in the first place. Guessing is just guessing, which is not a good thing.